# f is a function of a vector argument

Tags: mathematics

I read "*f is a scalar function of a vector argument.*". This means that the function f take one argument, and more specifically a vector (e.g. [1; 2.156; 1/3]), as input, and outputs a scalar, i.e. a simple real number (e.g. 1.159). E.g. f([1; 2.156; 1/3]) = 1.159.

I feel "of a vector argument" sounds weird. Is that correct, and if not what's the best way to phrase it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"*f is a function of [some argument]*" is completely correct terminology, specific to mathematics. From Columbia University's page "[What does "function of" mean?](http://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/projects/mmt/frontiers/web/chapter_3/9121.html)":

> A function defines one variable in terms of another. The statement "y is a function of x" (denoted y = y(x)) means that y varies according to whatever value x takes on.

Here, "*f is a function of a vector argument*," is the mathematically appropriate phrase to express that the function f is defined by an argument that is a vector.

As noted below in the comments, you can leave off "*argument*" since the "*...function of...*" construction assumes that the object of "*of*" is an argument.

Finally, this is a construction particular to the discipline of mathematics, so don't expect native English speakers to be generally familiar with it. (Most people I know understand it perfectly, but most people I know are computer programmers!)

Comment: Thanks! It sounds strange to my French ear, but I guess I'll get used to it :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It might sound a bit strange to many native English speakers, too, if they haven't studied mathematics :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If there's a weird bit here...I'd say it's only the lengthy *"f is a function of a vector **argument**"*...as opposed to *"f is a function of a vector"*.  When you start backing away from the convenience of mathematics contractions, you would expect other things to start expanding as well... such as to *"f is a function that takes a vector argument"*.  You either buy into the efficiency or you don't.

Comment: In physics, a common name for scalar functions that depend on a vector is "scalar field". Maybe you prefer it over the much longer expression?

Comment: For what it's worth: As a computer geek (albeit one who does not use Life gliders as his avatar -- yes, I saw what you did there), I think most of my friends would understand the phrase "[something] function of a [something] argument" just fine, though "scalar" and "vector" might not be recognized terms.